# I got null value from component attribute

Tags: apex, visualforce-component

I got `null` value for agreementId when I try to type it

Apex Class

```
public class selectedTasks {
    private final List<agreement__c> agreementTasks;
    public String agreementId {set;get;}

    public agreement__c selectedAgreement {set;get;}
    private String finalQuery = '';

    public selectedTasks() {
        try{
            agreementTasks = [SELECT name FROM agreement__c WHERE Id =:agreementId ];

        } catch(Exception e){
            errorMessage = 'Id : '+agreementId;
        }
    }
}
```

VF Component

```
<apex:component controller="selectedTasks" access="global">
    <apex:attribute assignTo="{!agreementId}" 
                    name="agrId" type="String" 
                    description="Agreement ID"
                    access="global"
                    required="true"/>
    {!errorMessage}
</apex:component>
```

VF Page

```
<apex:page >
  <c:Partner_Tasks_Component agrId="a0Z25000001cSXG" />
</apex:page>
```

Comment: How is "selectedTasks" being called? I think you've oversimplified your code.

Comment: @sfdcfox How can I call class ?? I thought it get and set values after load the component inside VF page

Comment: Your code *is* being called; by the time the page loads, the agreementId should be populated. Since you're not calling your function, none of the other stuff is populated, though. Let me write up an answer for you and see if it helps.

Comment: shouldn't `selectedTasks()` be `getSelectedTasks()` to be usable in VF component?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have faced similar issues earlier when using components. Seems, we are not able to use {get;set;} when working with components. Please try changing the below line from your code

```
public String agreementId {set;get;}
```

to

```
public String agreementId;

public void setAgreementId(String argId){
agreementId = argId;    
} 

public String getAgreementId(){
return agreementId; 
}
```

I have done similar changes in my controller and it has worked fine for me. Please see if this works for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Since you're trying to load an agreement record, I would change your class as follows:

```
public class selectedTasks {
    // Must be public or it won't be useful outside the class
    public Agreement__c agreement { get; set; }
    // Remember the Id in case we need it later.
    Id agreementId;
    public void setAgreementId(Id agreementId) {
        if(this.agreementId == null) {
            this.agreementId = agreementId;
            try {
                agreement = [SELECT Name FROM Agreement__c WHERE Id = :agreementId];
            } catch(QueryException e) {
                // The agreement could not be queried if we got here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I got the same error

Comment: What error are you getting, precisely?

Comment: I type the agreementId in VF page and its value is null. I added get method with default value (valid record Id) and it worked. so the problem is, agreement Id didn't passed from component attribute to the controller. It may cause of attribute type for example? or access? I gave it global access and the variable in the controller is public..